# Agent of passives introduced by "as to"

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice, subjects

[Page 68 of Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1WuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA68&ots=nmPt6BdbAQ&dq=%22when%20the%20uncertainty%20is%20less%20marked%2C%20or%20not%20present%22&hl=es&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q=%22when%20the%20uncertainty%20is%20less%20marked,%20or%20not%20present%22&f=false) reads

> **AS TO:** used after certain preceding passive clauses, e.g. *I am not much troubled **as to** its outward appearance*—G. Gissing, 1903;
> *I am also simultaneously bemused…**as to** why people should sunbathe indoors.*

Can the agents of passives introduced by "as to"?

Comment: Can you provide examples of the "agents of passives" that you are referring to?

Comment: @MikeBrockington I was bit(ten) _by **the dog**_

Comment: I can't see any way to use "as to" in that phrase - what did you have in mind?

Comment: @MikeBrockington I am not **much troubled** _as to_/by_ its outward appearance.

Comment: why is **bemused** a passive instead of an adjective in the OP example? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bemused#Adjective